# If we point a perpendicular laser beam from the bottom of a skyscraper to its peak should that beam be inclined?

Tags: kinematics, speed-of-light, earth

If we point a perpendicular laser beam from the bottom of a skyscraper to its peak should the beam be inclined due to Earth's motion+rotation even the pulse is making a perpendicular trajectory?

Comment: Are the top and the bottom of the skyscraper moving at the same speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of light is much faster than the rotation of the earth.  You are assuming that the time for light to travel from the base to the top of the skyscraper is significant relative to the rotation of Earth. The speed of light is **3 x 10 <sup>8</sup> m/s** while the earth rotates at the equater at about **460 m/s**.  With these velocity differences, the correction angle needed to hit the center of the top of the skyscraper is negligible.